# Php shell_exec en apache2 no funciona

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

estoy usando shell_exec en apache2 en un ubuntu pero no funciona.

Este es el codigo:

```
<?php 
 $command = "echo python /web.py";
 exec($command);
?>
```

No se si puede ser problema de apache o el php.ini. Me podeis ayudar? Gracias!

Comment: Comprueba la ruta al archivo "web.py"

Comment: Si lo hago por la terminal si que funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué aparece en el log de error del servidor apache? También sería bueno saber cuál es el valor de retorno de `exec()`, quizá se esté ejecutando y si no usas un `echo` no lo sabrás jamas, recuerda que estás haciendo un `echo` y eso no deja rastro para saber si se ejecutó bien o mal. Prueba `var_export(exec($command));`. PD: ¿Quieres usar `shell_exec()` o `exec()`?

Comment: He usado el shell_exec() i tampoco funciona. He probado lo mismo en windows y si me funciona por no se porque en ubuntu no.

Comment: ¿Podrías responder a la pregunta que te planteé y hacer la prueba que te propuse? Es decir, decirnos qué aparece en el log de error del servidor apache y que nos digas el valor de retorno de la llamada usando, por ejemplo, `var_export(exec($command));`. Gracias.

Comment: Si hago var_export(exec($command)); me devuelve: " , en los logs de apache no me sale ningun error.

Comment: Si hago esto: var_export(shell_exec($command));exit; el resultado es NULL

Comment: ¿Tu ubuntu está modificada o está proporcionada por algún proveedor de servicios? ¿Estás usando el servidor apache y el PHP que proporciona la distribución? ¿Qué versión exacta de ubuntu es? Estoy intentando reproducir tu problema y a mí me funciona correctamente todo. ¿Abro una sala de chat para hablar de este problema de manera más fluida?

Comment: Para agilizar el proceso de averiguar qué te ocurre, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88351/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-david).